# Does PostgreSQL's JSON type replace array type?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I want to store a simple array of VARCHAR in a PostgreSQL table. In the past, I would have used a column with array datatype, but most recent versions of PostgreSQL allow me to store JSON.

In a simple case like this, the recommedation is still to use the array type or should I transform my array of VARCHAR in a JSON array and store using the JSON type?

Answer (score 0):

I think these types are still different.

The array is just an Array, while JSON consists of attribute–value pairs. If you don't need these couples, JSON is useless, just more complex.

But, more important, is what you need. I mean, operations on array and json are different:

Array: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html

Json: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

So you need to evaluate what is best for your operations. Also, I suppose, depending of your operations, performances will differ.

Also, if think JSON fit better your needs, use BSON for better performances.